# Avoid URL in text message

Tags: url, sms

We have a database logic, which sends text messages to phone numbers using webservice. Part of the messages is the string "X.net", which is a brand name. However in the telephones when the message is received this gets transformed into an URL and gets blue letters and gets underlined (because of the ".net"). We would like to avoid this, and instead present this as a simple text. Is there any possibility to do this, and if yes, how?

Comment: If a client is determined to make "x.net" a link, there isn't much you can't do other than not sending "x.net". But I suppose since it's a brand name, you can't do "x dot net", can you?

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct, we can't change X.net, I tried to offer Xnet to our customer but they refused. I thought that it is the phone itself which transforms the text into a link, but I was hoping to find a way to "force" it as text.

Comment: If dot can be similar, you can use unicode 0x00b7, which is dot in the middle. This will trick phones to not process as link. You can not force phone to not process links via SMS unfortunately. They are "smart" phones :)